# Display flex. How to have second element displayed below first one.

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I have one obstacle to solve. I would like to have the element  below the  element. I used display-flex and do not know how to move elements labels straight below the select element? Is it possible with flex box, instead of using normal display:block; on each element?

Here is my code:

```
 <div class="choose-list">
                    <select name="priority" size="1">
                        <option value="wybierz z listy">wybierz z listy</option>
                        <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                        <option value="High">High</option>
                        <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>rodzaj domu</label>
                    <select name="priority" size="1">
                        <option value="wybierz z listy">wybierz z listy</option>
                        <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                        <option value="High">High</option>
                        <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>rodzaj zadaszenia</label>
                    <select name="priority" size="1">
                        <option value="wybierz z listy">wybierz z listy</option>
                        <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                        <option value="High">High</option>
                        <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>rodzaj stropu</label>
                    <select name="priority" size="1">
                        <option value="wybierz z listy">wybierz z listy</option>
                        <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                        <option value="High">High</option>
                        <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>garaż</label>
                </div>
```

And css file:

```
 .choose-list{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    label{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated based on a comment

Wrap each select/label and give them `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`

```css
.choose-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.choose-list > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="choose-list">
  <div>
    <select name="priority" size="1">
                        <option value="wybierz z listy">wybierz z listy</option>
                        <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                        <option value="High">High</option>
                        <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
                    </select>
    <label>rodzaj domu</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select name="priority" size="1">
                        <option value="wybierz z listy">wybierz z listy</option>
                        <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                        <option value="High">High</option>
                        <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
                    </select>
    <label>rodzaj zadaszenia</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select name="priority" size="1">
                        <option value="wybierz z listy">wybierz z listy</option>
                        <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                        <option value="High">High</option>
                        <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
                    </select>
    <label>rodzaj stropu</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select name="priority" size="1">
                        <option value="wybierz z listy">wybierz z listy</option>
                        <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                        <option value="High">High</option>
                        <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
                    </select>
    <label>garaż</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or give them a width of minimum 20.1%, add `flex-wrap: wrap` and set the label's order to 1

```css
.choose-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.choose-list > * {
  flex-basis: 20.1%;       /*  need a value greater than 20% 
                               so they break line after 4 items  */
}
.choose-list > label {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="choose-list">
    <select name="priority" size="1">
                        <option value="wybierz z listy">wybierz z listy</option>
                        <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                        <option value="High">High</option>
                        <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
                    </select>
    <label>rodzaj domu</label>
    <select name="priority" size="1">
                        <option value="wybierz z listy">wybierz z listy</option>
                        <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                        <option value="High">High</option>
                        <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
                    </select>
    <label>rodzaj zadaszenia</label>
    <select name="priority" size="1">
                        <option value="wybierz z listy">wybierz z listy</option>
                        <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                        <option value="High">High</option>
                        <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
                    </select>
    <label>rodzaj stropu</label>
    <select name="priority" size="1">
                        <option value="wybierz z listy">wybierz z listy</option>
                        <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                        <option value="High">High</option>
                        <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
                    </select>
    <label>garaż</label>
</div>
```